# F is entire such that exists $z_n\to \infty$ sequence such that $ F(z_n)\to 0$ Prove that...

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

F is entire such that exists  $z_n\to \infty$ sequence   that $ F(z_n)\to 0$ Prove that for every $c \in C$  exists $w_n\to \infty$ sequence such that $$F(w_n)\to c$$.

I know i have to change my initial sequence so that my function will go a bit further from zero. But don't know how to.

Comment: What is $00$? can you please explain

Comment: @Anubhav infinity

Comment: do you know what is essential singularity? Try to prove that $g(z)=F(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: @Anubhav how this will show that my  F can take any value?

Comment: What is the property of essential singularity?? Do you know. If not, then go back and read and think of this problem.

Comment: @Anubhav Casorati Weirstrass?